# Protecting Crystal Report Design and Source

Tags: crystal-reports

I have search everywhere on Internet to protect my source of Crystal Reports or protect them by any means but all in vain.

I am using **crystal-reports ver. 9**. and Developing Reports for an accounting and financing solution. and need to protect the reports that no one can mess with the reports.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Jamshaid Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with Crystal 9, you need to upgrade to Crystal 2011 or above and use RPTR file. RPTR file is a run-time report , which can be run as a normal report by the end user but cannot be edited. RPTR file is created from a regular report using export. You will keep the regular report (RPT file) for development and export it to RPTR and deploy it when it is necessary. There are some tools , which pretend that they secure any Crystal report file , but these are false statements and the files can be easily open in design mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot LAN. I found it.

Answer (score 1):

To make the report read-only:

Navigate to `File Menu --> Report Options -->Select the 'Read-only' check box-->click  'OK'`